# Disable HTML validation on a single RichText field

Tags: richtext-editor, validation

We have some integration running that's adding html with necessary data attributes to a RichText field, the validator is flashing this as invalid when it is valid in this use case.

How to disable the RichText html validation on a single template field?

The only options I have found are to disable for all RichText fields globally which is not what we want.

Comment: Did you check this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/remove-is-valid-xhtml-validation-rule-for-rich-text-field

Comment: @SumitBhatia yes that disables for ALL richtext fields, I need to only apply on a single template field

Comment: @SumitBhatia That example shows how to remove globally, and the edit shows how to only apply to RichText type... there's no example showing how to apply to a template field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now sure with the particular field but yes, If you want to remove the validation rules from a particular item, then you can do this by using a field on the item called `Suppressed Validation Rules`

According to the Sitecore document, Validation issues no longer appear in the Quick Action Bar if you suppress global validation rules on individual content items.

Refer to this document:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/the-validation-options.html

For example, you can use this one `Full Page XHtml, Item ID {9DE34911-96D5-48C3-AFFF-20CFF4D5AB02}`. And this is the item ID of the `Full Page XHtml` validation rule.

Read this thread for more details.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452005/how-do-i-turn-off-xhtml-validation-in-sitecore#:~:text=If%20you%20go%20into%20System,XHTML%20validation%20rule%20from%20there.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452005/how-do-i-turn-off-xhtml-validation-in-sitecore#:%7E:text=If%20you%20go%20into%20System,XHTML%20validation%20rule%20from%20there.)

Comment: This lets me do it on a content item or standard values, but I don't appear to have the Suppressed Validation Rules field on the template field itself. I can adapt this method and will accept it if there's no other solution put forwards

Comment: Full Page XHtml, Item ID {9DE34911-96D5-48C3-AFFF-20CFF4D5AB02} didn't work for me. The trick is to add just the GUID to the Suppressed Validation Rules. So just add {9DE34911-96D5-48C3-AFFF-20CFF4D5AB02}. Also, this did not suppress the Rich Text Editor IsXhtml warnings. So I had to add {CB57D0E7-5202-4C3D-838B-314F2B95A2CB} instead to the Suppressed Validation Rules.

Answer (score 1):

`Full Page XHtml, Item ID {9DE34911-96D5-48C3-AFFF-20CFF4D5AB02}` didn't work for me. The trick is to add just the GUID to the Suppressed Validation Rules. So, just add `{9DE34911-96D5-48C3-AFFF-20CFF4D5AB02}`. Also, this did not suppress the Rich Text Editor IsXhtml warnings. So I had to add `{CB57D0E7-5202-4C3D-838B-314F2B95A2CB}` instead. Hope this helps.